# Connect To A Specific Host

Tags: ssh

So I am working in a place which is designed viz.

[image]
So whenever I login with `ssh` I am `thor@my_username`.

Now I am asked to access the `host` named `loki`. How can do that?

I only have the `thor` ip-address:port info and that `loki` is a host and `thor` is the entrypoint as shown in the graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot connect to the host named *loki* through the firewall you may be able to connect to it after having logged in to the *thor* host by logging in to *thor* and then using ssh from there to connect to *loki*.

You could do this from bash (or another shell) by entering:

```
ssh user@loki
```

This assumes that the *thor* host has the ability to resolve (find the IP for) *loki*